# Know where the cursor is in the text using AceEditor in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I am creating a code editor and now I would like to know what is the position of the cursor is in the Ace Editor text.

This is the code of component of code editor:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/theme/monokai';
import 'brace/ext/language_tools';

class EditorCodeEditor extends Component {
  onChange = e => {
    // Here  I want show for console the position of cursor
    Something like this? -> console.log(this.refs.ace.editor.focus);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AceEditor
          mode="javascript"
          theme="monokai"
          name="blah2"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          fontSize={14}
          showPrintMargin={true}
          showGutter={true}
          highlightActiveLine={true}
          value="I AM AN EDITOR"
          ref='ace'
          focus={true}
          cursorStart={1}
          editorProps={{$blockScrolling: true}}
          style={{width: '100%', height: '400px'}}
          setOptions={{
            enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
            enableSnippets: true,
            showLineNumbers: true,
            tabSize: 2
          }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditorCodeEditor;
```

> The problem is when I use *ref='ace'* in AceEditor label, it returns the
>   error: **Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated.
>   (react/no-string-refs)** and the same with *this.refs* into onChange function.

Any idea for this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `ref={c => { this.ace = c; }}`

Comment: Thanks, this is accepted, but how should I call this inside the console.log?

Comment: Like `this.ace.focus()`

Comment: Returns an undefined. I don't what is the reason.

Comment: The component should be mounted before `this.ace` is set.

Comment: I think this is so. The component is exactly like in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173603/discussion-between-vijayst-and-belen-dominguez-garcia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ref prop refers to the DOM node. And can be accessed via the following code:

```
ref={c => { this.ace = c; }}
```

For getting the position of the cursor, AceEditor has an onCursorChange prop that you can use.

```
onCursorChange(selection) {
  const cursorPosition = selection.getCursor();
}
```

Comment: You have made my day. This is just what I needed. Thank you very much!